# Am I Properly Sending Hex Commands Over Serial Via C Program

Tags: c, serial-port, c89

I am writing C89 code to send hex commands to an HDMI Monoprice 4x2 matrix switch via RS232. The code I have written controls HDMI ports 2-4 just fine, but will not switch to port 1. I have identical code for all 4 HDMI ports (With proper control codes for each).

```
sprintf(system_command, "%c%c%c%c", 0x00, 0xFF, 0xD5, 0x7B); // prepare HDMI1
```

And after this I am logging what each byte should be in this array:

```
    LOG_1("after we prep command system_command (x)1 - %02x", system_command[0]);
    LOG_1("after we prep command system_command (x)2 - %02x", system_command[1]);
    LOG_1("after we prep command system_command (x)3 - %02x", system_command[2]);
    LOG_1("after we prep command system_command (x)4 - %02x", system_command[3]);
```

Which results in the following, note the longer values for bytes 2 and 3:

```
after we prep command system_command (x)1 - 01
after we prep command system_command (x)2 - fffffffe
after we prep command system_command (x)3 - ffffffd5
after we prep command system_command (x)4 - 7b
```

The odd thing is that I get these same results with the proper values for HDMI2, 3 and 4; with no problems switching inputs.

```
sprintf(system_command, "%c%c%c%c", 0x01, 0xFE, 0xD5, 0x7B);
after we prep command system_command (x)1 - 01
after we prep command system_command (x)2 - fffffffe
after we prep command system_command (x)3 - ffffffd5
after we prep command system_command (x)4 - 7b
```

Why would this work with all but one of the inputs on this device?

Moreover am I populating and reading these hex bytes properly?

I will also add that this same program works with multiple other devices.

Comment: Your `LOG_1`s are probably exhibiting undefined behavior due to passing negative signed integers to a function in the `fprintf()`-family with a `%x`-conversion specifier..

Comment: How is defined `system_command`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type of `system_command` is an array of `char`, then on your system `char` is *signed*.

What happens is that the compiler does [default argument promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions) of the arguments of the variable argument `printf` function, which converts `char` to `int`. And when that happens it does also do *sign extension*.

The solution I recommend is to use the explicit `uint8_t` type instead of plain `char`. The `uint8_t` type is a type-alias (a `typedef`) of `unsigned char`, which you can use if you don't have the [fixed-width integers from `<stdint.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).

I also recommend you stop using string functions (like `sprintf`) to handle the data, you are not working with strings but binary data. Remember that the all strings in C are terminated with the special character `'\0'` which is equal to zero. Now what do you think happens if you use string functions and the data contains a zero somewhere in the middle?

---

To actually answer the question, if you are sending the data correctly, then the answer is yes. The data is sent correctly and the problem is your presentation of the data.